# Intranet site Content Management

Tags: content-management-system, intranet, content-management

I'm currently designing my very first Website for a small business Intranet (5 pages). Can anyone recommend the best way to manage content for the Company News section? I don't really want to get involved in day to day content updates so something that would be **simple** for the Marketing guy to create and upload a simple news article, perhaps created in MS Word, lets assume the author has no html skills.

I've read about Content Management systems but,

A. I won't get any funding for purchase and
 B. Think it's a bit overkill for a small 5 page internal website.

It's been an unexpected hurdle in my plans, for something that I'd assumed would be a fairly common functionality I can't seem to find any definitive articles to suit my needs.
I'm open to suggestions (even if it's confirmation that a CMS is the only way to go).

Comment: Try Pixie CMS, small, simple and free.

Comment: You might find some pointers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402468/using-a-content-management-system-for-a-simple-original-website

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are : small site, no budget and the need for it to be easy for the marketing guy to upload a news item.

My recommendation would be to go with an all in one CMS e.g wordpress which has the kind of functionality you're talking about out of the box.

My guess is this organisation is just getting into "intranets" so something quick and simple that can be used to justify expenditure if value is returned is the key. Perhaps look at a plugin that automatically emails a summary of the blog posts to all employees once a week would be useful ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options and you can use any one of these:

- Joomla
- SilverStripe CMS
- ModX
- Cushy CMS
- Frog CMS
- Drupal

Answer (score 0):

Additional in what Mr. Mckinnon said, you must keep in mind that if you don't want to get involved in daily updates of the people who is going to use the platform, you should consider the following:

- What kind of data you want to be displayed
- Who can view/modify that data
- Who can create/remove data
- How you will be organizing all that data

Your intranet should not be limited to display or create data, eventually all that data can turn into a beautiful Knowledge Base (KB) for your company that eventually your coworkers can share their solutions to common and rare problems that company can present eventually. This KB is amazing and time-saving, it is recommended to start it as soon as possible, so newcomers to your Company have access to it and see the most common issues and they can enter into production asap (we all know time is a luxury in every company regarding size).

Just keep in mind too, that all that knowledge and data is beyond valuable to you and your coworkers, so you should also consider some additional login credentials so your Company System Administrator can manage those credentials and also eventual audit for unauthorized access (if applicable).

I hope this helps from the administrative point of view